# Android studio installation error on Mac OS 10.12.3

Tags: android-studio, macos-sierra

On installing Android studio on Mac OS, I am getting the below attached error messages.
Any ideas on how to stop this error. This is not letting me install the SDK.

[image]

Comment: You may find your answer
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736242/android-studio-sdk-installation-failed-mac-os-x).