# Android Studio SDK Installation Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I am trying to install Android Studio in Mac OS 10.12.3
I downloaded Android Studio v2.3 for mac.

It installs successfully, but when setting up for the first time, it always shows this error.

> An error occurred while trying to compute required packages.

On clicking finish, i get

> Failed to determine required packages

When i try to open SDK Manager, all options are disabled and it shows [this][3]. Even if i click on set sdk location, it gives me the same error as before.

I searched a lot in stack overflow and tried many suggestions, but nothing worked till now.

Things i tried:

- Changed proxy settings, and added *.dl.google.com, *.dl-ssl.google.com in bypass proxys.
- In android studio preferences, changed it to 'Auto Detect Proxy Settings'
- Disabled Tunnelblick (i use it for VPN).
- Deleted ~/.android everytime before trying
- Changed permission to selected SDK folder to 777
- Tried to run installer with sudo
- Different SDK installer location

Comment: I am not sure this is the right place to ask this

Comment: I just had the same with exactly the same versions of android studio and macos

Comment: Same, on Ubuntu, maybe some server down.

Comment: Getting `com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils$PackageResolutionException: Dependant package with key emulator not found!` in the log.

Comment: Same thing here on osx. I guess something is down :(

Comment: I'd like the question title to remove "Mac OS" as the procedure is the same for any system I believe. The answer given here (Daniel Money's one, that should be accepted as the default answer) solved my problem, and I'm on a Linux system. Including "Mac OS" probably prevent some people to apply this solution.

Answer (score 13):

Once you've failed the install, click Finish (I believe twice) to get to the Android SDK launcher.  Click on Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates and change the Update Channel to "Canary Channel".

Close out of the SDK and relaunch the Android Studio.  It should go forward w/o issue.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks man! I think it should be the accepted answer since it's really simple

Comment: Thanks man. I wish i knew this before. Would have saved me a day.

Comment: Still worked in 2021!

Comment: Wow, this is a bit ridiculous, worked on Apple Silicon M1Pro for AS (2020.3.1)

Comment: Don't work for me . Still have this error. com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils$PackageResolutionException: Dependant package with key emulator not found!
Error from terminal

Comment: Nice! @digantadas you should mark this answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a lot of search, and asking for help, i found something. Maybe it can help someone else.

I still didn't figure out what was the problem, but i got a workaround.

Since android studio couldn't install SDK, i used homebrew to install android-sdk separately, and then linked that folder as ANDROID_HOME and then set that path in Android Studio SDK, and it worked.

There was some more problems i faced in updating SDK Tools, but updating from command line did the trick.

Now all works fine.